# Why the Survey Corps doesn't find a human body inside each titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In Attack on Titan (anime), up till now we are given information that the "dumb" titans that wonder outside the walls are *probably* humans. Given that both "smart" (Eren/Annie/Yumir/etc) and "dumb" titans share the same weakness this has always been a possibility.

However, its not clear why the Survey Corps never finds the bodies of the humans inside the "dumb" titans? They should at least find the bones of the human. Is this a logical flaw of the series?

BTW: please, no spoilers from the manga, only info available in the anime up to season 2 episode 12.

Comment: The answer is a spoiler from the manga.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not a logical flaw in the series. Unfortunately, that information was only touched on in the last episode of Season 2. You've stated you don't want to hear spoilers about the manga. The anime ended right when the humans suspect regular titans are humans too. The last episode of Season 2 of the anime actually cuts out part of the conversation between Pixis, Hange, Levi, and Erwin where they address this. I assume either they will pick up in season 3 at that same discussion or use a flashback at some point to reveal the rest of what was said there. There's really nothing more I can say without spoilers, because I don't think the anime has given enough information to deduce what's going on at this point.